# extracting corresponding values in the column of dynamic webtable based on the given xpath using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have following dynamic webtable

```
(checkbox)   ID_No  country_code  Date          Time                  FileName
            1A       5J           10/04/2019    12:05:45           filename_12:05
            1A       5J           10/04/2019    13:05:45           filename2
            3A       8J           10/03/2019    14:05:45           filename2
            4A       9J           10/04/2019    14:08:45           filename1
```

On the left hand side of the id_no there is a checkbox.

I have following dataframe

```
ID_No  country_code  Date            Time               FileName
1A       5J           10/04/2019    
1A       5J           10/04/2019
```

I only want to check the rows in the dynamic webtable correspoing to the matching country_code,ID_No 
and Date in the dataframe,and populate the Time and filename values in the dataframe

I am writing below code in a loop selecting 1 checkbox at a time

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
        id_no=row['ID_No']
        country_code=row['country_code']
        date=row['Date']
        driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
        driver.get(website_URL) 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and 
        td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)] ]//input").click()
```

in this case country_code='5J' and ID_No='1A' and Date='10/04/2019'
when I use this xpath in the chrome console:

```
$x("//tr[td[contains(text(),'10/04/2019')] and 
td[contains(text(),'5J')] and td[contains(text(),'1A')] ]")[0]
```

This contains 1st row that satisfies above condition.I get following HTML for the rows of this webtable

```
<tr class="class1">
  <td width="2%"> </td>   <!–– checkbox ––>
  <td width="2%"> 1A </td>
  <td width="2%"> 5J </td>
  <td width="2%"> 10/04/2019 </td>
  <td width="2%"> 12:05:45 </td>
  <td width="2%"> filename_12:05 </td>
</tr>
```

How can I extract corresponding filename and time from the dynamic webtable corresponding to the checkboxes I select?

in the above case,in the first iteration,`extracted_filename='filename_12:05' and time='12:05:45'`
second_iteration,`extracted_filename='filename2' and time='13:05:45`

Comment: You can try xpath axes.

//tr[td[contains(text(),'10/04/2019')] and 
td[contains(text(),'5J')] and td[contains(text(),'1A')] ]//td[5]

//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and 
        td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)] ]//td[5] : Time

//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and 
        td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)] ]//td[6] : File Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try these xpaths and let me know how it goes.

This will give you the time of matching row

```
time= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)] ]//input/../following-sibling::td[4]").text
```

This will give you the file name of matching row

```
filename=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)]]//input/../following-sibling::td[5]").text
```

With your code:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
            id_no=row['ID_No']
            country_code=row['country_code']
            date=row['Date']
            driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
            driver.get(website_URL) 
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)] ]//input").click()
            time= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)] ]//input/../following-sibling::td[4]").text
            filename=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(),date)] and td[contains(text(),country_code)] and td[contains(text(),id_no)]]//input/../following-sibling::td[5]").text
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle dynamic element Induce `WebDriverWait` and following xpath.

## Return Time

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//tr[td[contains(text(),'" + date + "')] and  td[contains(text(),'" + country_code +"')] and td[contains(text(),'" + id_no + "')] ]//input/following::td[4]"))).text)
```

## Return File name

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//tr[td[contains(text(),'" + date + "')] and  td[contains(text(),'" + country_code +"')] and td[contains(text(),'" + id_no + "')] ]//input/following::td[5]"))).text)
```

To execute above code you need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```